# displaying count of array gives binary result

Tags: php, arrays, arguments

Query mentioned below fetches 2 row from database.I have stored the query results in array which I have passed as argument to the function.

```
$user = array();
$sql="select * from user_table where parent_id='60' ";
$result =mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $user[]= $row['id']; 
}

test_function($user);
```

My user defined function looks like this.

```
test_function(array $id_arg)
{
  echo count($id_arg);
}
```

I presume it must echo 2 which is the number of rows from query result 
**but in fact it is displaying**

**0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0**

Am I missing something.

Any helps are welcomed.

Comment: Try var_dump($id_arg) instead of echo.  You get more data.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure but try mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_both instead of mysql_fetch_array

Comment: Why should OP "try this" ?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array gives result with an indexed array so you cannot use something like $user['id']. Instead you can use $user[0]. Any how this is not related to your issue but I can see only one mistake in your code

Comment: @roudrabhaskaruduthammali it actually returns both by default